# How do I load test with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing, load

Does anyone have any information on this? I'm currently running Visual Studio Team System 2008 v9.0.21022.8 RTM and have been told that I am able to do load testing on my project.

Sadly, when I right-click the project node there is no 'Load Test' under 'Add'...

I'm thinking the load testing functionality might be an extra, but thought I'd ask here before making a fool of myself to my boss :-)

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add tests to just any project, you have to specifically create a new test project in your solution.

Right-click the solution node > Add > New Project... > Visual C# > Test > Test Project

You'll be able to add unit, web and load tests to this new project.

In order to actually do load testing, you have to develop individual unit tests or webtests first.  Then you add these to a load test and you're off to the races.

Comment: That worked for me, but didn't have the opportunity to add a new project from right-clicking the solution node. Just went the file menu instead. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In vs2010. Add Test Project. Then Add Load Test to that project.